# Why is Firefox changing the color calibration of this image?

Tags: graphics

The symptom of my problem is that the same hex color in a PNG image does not match the CSS-defined color defined by the same hex code.

This problem only happens in Firefox when `gfx.color_management.mode` is set to `2` (tagged images only) rather than `0` (off). (Firefox ICC color correction described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/ICC_color_correction_in_Firefox)).

The image is http://dzfk93w6juz0e.cloudfront.net/images/background-top-light.png which at the bottom has the color `#c8e8bd`. However, the shade of green is different to that color when Firefox color calibration is enabled.

Is this image inadvertently "tagged" for color correction?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your image is tagged with a print profile, which is probably why you're seeing a different color. As stated on [this article from Hacks Mozilla](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/color-correction/):

> You can remove all of the color correction chunks resulting in an untagged image using pngcrush:
>
> > pngcrush -rem gAMA -rem cHRM -rem iCCP -rem sRGB infile.png outfile.png
>
> Alternatively, you can use [TweakPNG](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/) and delete the gAMA, cHRM, iCCP and sRGB chunks by hand.